# How to Change background-color of .body when hover menu ( Jquery - Shopify )?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover, shopify

I've put a megamenu to my shopify website, whcih work pefectly,

However, I'd like to have the background color of my website fade-in when I hover the menu ..  To have exactly the same result as this website:

http://www.johnlewis.com/

I've try to add this function:

```
$(function(){
 $('.dc-mega').hover(function(){$('html').css('background-color','#676767') } );
});
```

But didnt work out .. .

here is the full jquery code of my megamenu (Js file) ..  if it may help .. . Would really appreciate it, thank you so much !:

/*
 * DC Mega Menu - jQuery mega menu
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Design Chemical
 *
 */
(function($){

```
//define the defaults for the plugin and how to call it 
$.fn.dcMegaMenu = function(options){
    //set default options  
    var defaults = {
        classParent: 'dc-mega',
        classContainer: 'sub-container',
        classSubParent: 'mega-hdr',
        classSubLink: 'mega-hdr',
        classWidget: 'dc-extra',
        rowItems: 5,
        speed: 'fast',
        effect: 'fade',
        event: 'hover',
        fullWidth: false,
        onLoad : function(){},
        beforeOpen : function(){},
        beforeClose: function(){}
    };

    //call in the default otions
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var $dcMegaMenuObj = this;

    //act upon the element that is passed into the design    
    return $dcMegaMenuObj.each(function(options){

        var clSubParent = defaults.classSubParent;
        var clSubLink = defaults.classSubLink;
        var clParent = defaults.classParent;
        var clContainer = defaults.classContainer;
        var clWidget = defaults.classWidget;

        megaSetup();

        function megaOver(){
            var subNav = $('.sub',this);
            $(this).addClass('mega-hover');
            if(defaults.effect == 'fade'){
                $(subNav).fadeIn(defaults.speed);
            }
            if(defaults.effect == 'slide'){
                $(subNav).show(defaults.speed);
            }
            // beforeOpen callback;
            defaults.beforeOpen.call(this);
        }
        function megaAction(obj){
            var subNav = $('.sub',obj);
            $(obj).addClass('mega-hover');
            if(defaults.effect == 'fade'){
                $(subNav).fadeIn(defaults.speed);
            }
            if(defaults.effect == 'slide'){
                $(subNav).show(defaults.speed);
            }
            // beforeOpen callback;
            defaults.beforeOpen.call(this);
        }
        function megaOut(){
            var subNav = $('.sub',this);
            $(this).removeClass('mega-hover');
            $(subNav).hide();
            // beforeClose callback;
            defaults.beforeClose.call(this);
        }
        function megaActionClose(obj){
            var subNav = $('.sub',obj);
            $(obj).removeClass('mega-hover');
            $(subNav).hide();
            // beforeClose callback;
            defaults.beforeClose.call(this);
        }
        function megaReset(){
            $('li',$dcMegaMenuObj).removeClass('mega-hover');
            $('.sub',$dcMegaMenuObj).hide();
        }

        function megaSetup(){
            $arrow = '<span class="dc-mega-icon"></span>';
            var clParentLi = clParent+'-li';
            var menuWidth = $dcMegaMenuObj.outerWidth();
            $('> li',$dcMegaMenuObj).each(function(){
                //Set Width of sub
                var $mainSub = $('> ul',this);
                var $primaryLink = $('> a',this);
                if($mainSub.length){
                    $primaryLink.addClass(clParent).append($arrow);
                    $mainSub.addClass('sub').wrap('<div class="'+clContainer+'" />');

                    var pos = $(this).position();
                    pl = pos.left;

                    if($('ul',$mainSub).length){
                        $(this).addClass(clParentLi);
                        $('.'+clContainer,this).addClass('mega');
                        $('> li',$mainSub).each(function(){
                            if(!$(this).hasClass(clWidget)){
                                $(this).addClass('mega-unit');
                                if($('> ul',this).length){
                                    $(this).addClass(clSubParent);
                                    $('> a',this).addClass(clSubParent+'-a');
                                } else {
                                    $(this).addClass(clSubLink);
                                    $('> a',this).addClass(clSubLink+'-a');
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        // Create Rows
                        var hdrs = $('.mega-unit',this);
                        rowSize = parseInt(defaults.rowItems);
                        for(var i = 0; i < hdrs.length; i+=rowSize){
                            hdrs.slice(i, i+rowSize).wrapAll('<div class="row" />');
                        }

                        // Get Sub Dimensions & Set Row Height
                        $mainSub.show();

                        // Get Position of Parent Item
                        var pw = $(this).width();
                        var pr = pl + pw;

                        // Check available right margin
                        var mr = menuWidth - pr;

                        // // Calc Width of Sub Menu
                        var subw = $mainSub.outerWidth();
                        var totw = $mainSub.parent('.'+clContainer).outerWidth();
                        var cpad = totw - subw;

                        if(defaults.fullWidth == true){
                            var fw = menuWidth - cpad;
                            $mainSub.parent('.'+clContainer).css({width: fw+'px'});
                            $dcMegaMenuObj.addClass('full-width');
                        }
                        var iw = $('.mega-unit',$mainSub).outerWidth(true);
                        var rowItems = $('.row:eq(0) .mega-unit',$mainSub).length;
                        var inneriw = iw * rowItems;
                        var totiw = inneriw + cpad;

                        // Set mega header height
                        $('.row',this).each(function(){
                            $('.mega-unit:last',this).addClass('last');
                            var maxValue = undefined;
                            $('.mega-unit > a',this).each(function(){
                                var val = parseInt($(this).height());
                                if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < val){
                                    maxValue = val;
                                }
                            });
                            $('.mega-unit > a',this).css('height',maxValue+'px');
                            $(this).css('width',inneriw+'px');
                        });

                        // Calc Required Left Margin incl additional required for right align

                        if(defaults.fullWidth == true){
                            params = {left: 0};
                        } else {

                            var ml = mr < ml ? ml + ml - mr : (totiw - pw)/2;
                            var subLeft = pl - ml;

                            // If Left Position Is Negative Set To Left Margin
                            var params = {left: pl+'px', marginLeft: -ml+'px'};

                            if(subLeft < 0){
                                params = {left: 0};
                            }else if(mr < ml){
                                params = {right: 0};
                            }
                        }
                        $('.'+clContainer,this).css(params);

                        // Calculate Row Height
                        $('.row',$mainSub).each(function(){
                            var rh = $(this).height();
                            $('.mega-unit',this).css({height: rh+'px'});
                            $(this).parent('.row').css({height: rh+'px'});
                        });
                        $mainSub.hide();

                    } else {
                        $('.'+clContainer,this).addClass('non-mega').css('left',pl+'px');
                    }
                }
            });
            // Set position of mega dropdown to bottom of main menu
            var menuHeight = $('> li > a',$dcMegaMenuObj).outerHeight(true);
            $('.'+clContainer,$dcMegaMenuObj).css({top: menuHeight+'px'}).css('z-index','1000');

            if(defaults.event == 'hover'){
                // HoverIntent Configuration
                var config = {
                    sensitivity: 2,
                    interval: 100,
                    over: megaOver,
                    timeout: 0,
                    out: megaOut
                };
                $('li',$dcMegaMenuObj).hoverIntent(config);
            }

            if(defaults.event == 'click'){

                $('body').mouseup(function(e){
                    if(!$(e.target).parents('.mega-hover').length){
                        megaReset();
                    }
                });

                $('> li > a.'+clParent,$dcMegaMenuObj).click(function(e){
                    var $parentLi = $(this).parent();
                    if($parentLi.hasClass('mega-hover')){
                        megaActionClose($parentLi);
                    } else {
                        megaAction($parentLi);
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }

            // onLoad callback;
            defaults.onLoad.call(this);
        }
    });
};
 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.mouseover()` effect from jQuery library (check [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/))

I created an example JSFiddle with similar effect to what you wanted to achieve: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/13e0aLyt/48/)

**Explanation:**
Div `bg` is over everything else except the menu bar. It is just a half-transparent black div imitating greying backgorund. Default it is not displayed but when you hover menu bar it appears. Menu is under this div so it is normally visible. The menu also changes to show more content. If you need any more explanation to particular code section just ask in comments below.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what the end HTML looks like.

My guess is the background-color is somehow/overridden set on a lower level (on the body maybe ?)

Also, the `.hover` takes two arguments, as the first one is the mouse-enter callback, and the second the mouse-leave callback. Your current code just add the background-color and never removes it.

Check the API : http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your commment, You can check the html here: https://tibo-inspaces.myshopify.com/